# What's wrong with my vector<T>::erase here?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have two `vector<T>` in my program, called `active` and `non_active` respectively.  This refers to the objects it contains, as to whether they are in use or not.

I have some code that loops the `active` vector and checks for any objects that might have gone non active.  I add these to a `temp_list` inside the loop.

Then *after* the loop, I take my `temp_list` and do `non_active.insert` of all elements in the `temp_list`.

After that, I do call `erase` on my `active` vector and pass it the `temp_list` to erase.

For some reason, however, the `erase` crashes.

This is the code:

```
non_active.insert(non_active.begin(), temp_list.begin(), temp_list.end());
active.erase(temp_list.begin(), temp_list.end());
```

I get this assertion:

```
Expression:("_Pvector == NULL || (((_Myvec*)_Pvector)->_Myfirst <= _Ptr && _Ptr <= ((_Myvect*)_Pvector)->_Mylast)",0)
```

I've looked online and seen that there is a erase-remove idiom, however not sure how I'd apply that to a removing a range of elements from a `vector<T>`

I'm not using C++11.

Comment: Instead of describing what your code does, it would be much more useful to see the code, or better yet a small testcase. I have no idea how temp_list looks, but it seems you are trying to erase from `active` by passing iterators that "point" to a different container.

Comment: Could it be, that the `temp_list` iterator is not pointing to any valid position in active? Wouldn't you need here an iterator of active?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`erase` expects a range of iterators passed to it that lie within the current vector. You cannot pass iterators obtained from a different vector to `erase`.

Here is a possible, but inefficient, C++11 solution supported by lambdas:

```
active.erase(std::remove_if(active.begin(), active.end(), [](const T& x)
{
    return std::find(temp_list.begin(), temp_list.end(), x) != temp_list.end();
}), active.end());
```

And here is the equivalent C++03 solution without the lambda:

```
template<typename Container>
class element_of
{
    Container& container;

    element_of(Container& container) : container(container) {}

public:

    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& x) const
    {
        return std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), x)
            != container.end();
    }
};

// ...

active.erase(std::remove_if(active.begin(), active.end(),
                            element_of<std::vector<T> >(temp_list)),
             active.end());
```

If you replace `temp_list` with a `std::set` and the `std::find_if` with a `find` member function call on the set, the performance should be acceptable.

Comment: Note his last sentence, where he tells *I'm not using C++11*.

Comment: @Christian: Replace the lambda with a named functor then.

Comment: @Xeo Well in fact you're both right, but I would prefer not giving solutions in a completely different language. I wouldn't give him a C-based solution either, even if it would be easier to type. You could just use pseudo-code. This would still not be transferable into working code one-to-one, but it wouldn't pretend to be, either.

Comment: @ChristianRau: code in the wrong language _is_ psudocode for the right one.  Also, in this case, the differences are pretty minimal.

Comment: @MooingDuck And this minimality is the problem, as nowhere in the answer its C++11ness is mentioned in any way. It just stands there as a C++ solution for his problem, which it isn't.

Comment: @Xeo Yeah, indeed much better. It may seem pedantic from me, hadn't the OP explicitly denied C++11 (for what reason ever) with the answerer just ignoring (or at least seeming to ignore) this fact.

Comment: @ChristianRau I provided the equivalent C++03 solution in the meantime.

Comment: @FredOverflow Ah, nice! But you need to specify the container type in the `element_of` constructor call, don't you?

Comment: @ChristianRau Thanks, corrected. Wow, did functional programming really suck *that* badly in C++ before lambdas? :)

Answer (score 3):

The erase method is intended to accept iterators to the same container object. You're trying to pass in iterators to temp_list to use to erase elements from active which is not allowed for good reasons, as a Sequence's range erase method is intended to specify a range *in that Sequence* to remove. It's important that the iterators are in that sequence because otherwise we're specifying a range of values to erase rather than a range within the same container which is a much more costly operation.

The type of logic you're trying to perform suggests to me that a set or list might be better suited for the purpose. That is, you're trying to erase various elements from the middle of a container that match a certain condition and transfer them to another container, and you could eliminate the need for temp_list this way.

With list, for example, it could be as easy as this:

```
for (ActiveList::iterator it = active.begin(); it != active.end();)
{
    if (it->no_longer_active())
    {
        inactive.push_back(*it);
        it = active.erase(it);
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

However, sometimes vector can outperform these solutions, and maybe you have need for vector for other reasons (like ensuring contiguous memory). In that case, std::remove_if is your best bet.

Example:

```
bool not_active(const YourObjectType& obj);
active_list.erase(
    remove_if(active_list.begin(), active_list.end(), not_active), 
    active_list.end());
```

More info on this can be found under the topic, 'erase-remove idiom' and you may need predicate function objects depending on what external states are required to determine if an object is no longer active.

Comment: You make a valid point.  I never considered my needs in regards to memory etc, I just used a vector, cause that's what I normally use.

Comment: In that case your life would be a lot easier I think with list or set as you can simply remove elements from the middle of those in constant-time for list or logarithmic time for set (both quite fast). Erasing elements individually from the middle of a vector is a linear time operation which is quite slow (though remove_if allows this to be done for multiple elements matching a condition in a single pass). If you use list, you can simply iterate through active, check if it's no longer active, insert the element to inactive and erase from active all in one loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually make the erase/remove idiom usable for your case. You just need to move the value over to the other container *before* `std::remove_if` possibly shuffles it around: in the predicate.

```
template<class OutIt, class Pred>
struct copy_if_predicate{
  copy_if_predicate(OutIt dest, Pred p)
    : dest(dest), pred(p) {}

  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T const& v){
    if(pred(v)){
      *dest++ = v;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  OutIt dest;
  Pred pred;
};

template<class OutIt, class Pred>
copy_if_predicate<OutIt,Pred> copy_if_pred(OutIt dest, Pred pred){
  return copy_if_predicate<OutIt,Pred>(dest,pred);
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/7NYxy) (I directly used `bool`s to make the code shorter, not bothering with output and the likes.)

Comment: Personally, I don't think predicates with side-effects are a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The function `std::vector::erase` requires the iterators to be iterators into this vector, but you are passing iterators from `temp_list`. You cannot erase elements from a container that are in a completely different container.

Answer (score 1):

```
active.erase(temp_list.begin(), temp_list.end());
```

You try to erase elements from one list, but you use iterators for second list. First list iterators aren't the same, like in second list.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that this is an example of where `std::list` should be used. You can splice members from one list to another. Look at [std::list::splice()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/splice/)for this.

Do you need random access? If not then you don't need a `std::vector`.

Note that with list, when you splice, your iterators, and references to the objects in the list remain valid.

If you don't mind making the implementation "intrusive", your objects can contain their own iterator value, so they know where they are. Then when they change state, they can automate their own "moving" from one list to the other, and you don't need to transverse the whole list for them. (If you want this sweep to happen later, you can get them to "register" themselves for later moving).

I will write an algorithm here now to run through one collection and if a condition exists, it will effect a std::remove_if but at the same time will copy the element into your "inserter".

```
 //fwd iterator must be writable
template< typename FwdIterator, typename InputIterator, typename Pred >
FwdIterator copy_and_remove_if( FwdIterator inp, FwdIterator end, InputIterator outp, Pred pred )
{
    for( FwdIterator test = inp; test != end; ++test )
    {
        if( pred(*test) ) // insert
        {
            *outp = *test;
            ++outp;
        }
        else // keep
        {
           if( test != inp )
           { 
              *inp = *test;
           }
           ++inp;
        }
   }
   return inp;
}
```

This is a bit like `std::remove_if` but will copy the ones being removed into an alternative collection. You would invoke it like this (for a vector) where isInactive is a valid predicate that indicates it should be moved.

```
active.erase( copy_and_remove_if( active.begin(), active.end(), std::back_inserter(inactive), isInactive ), active.end() );
```

Comment: Sorry, but `remove_if` *will not work*. ["The elements between the old and the new ends of the range have unspecified values."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Answer (score 0):

The iterators you pass to `erase()` should point into the `vector` itself; the assertion is telling you that they don't. This version of `erase()` is for erasing a range out of the `vector`.

You need to iterate over `temp_list` yourself and call `active.erase()` on the result of dereferencing the iterator at each step.